# Compute the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(1-2\pi\cos(x)+\pi^2)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

My idea was to let $n=1+\pi^2$ so that I get an easier function to integrate.
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial n}\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(n-2\pi\cos(x))dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{n-2\pi\cos(x)}$$
Then I let $u=\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{1+u^2}\frac{du}{n-2\pi\left ( \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2} \right )}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{u^2(2\pi+n)+n-2\pi}du$$
$$\frac{2}{2\pi+n}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{du}{u^2+\frac{n-2\pi}{n+2\pi}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2-4\pi^2}}$$
Of course, we have to integrate $n$ back using trig-sub $n=2\pi\sec\theta$:
$$\int \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2-4\pi^2}}dn=\int\frac{2\pi^2\sec\theta\tan\theta}{2\pi\tan\theta}d\theta=\pi\ln\left ( \frac{n}{2\pi}+\tan\left ( \sec^{-1}\left(\frac{n}{2\pi}\right) \right ) \right )$$
Plugging $n=\pi^2+1$, I get: $\pi\ln\left(\frac{\pi^2+1}{2\pi}+\frac{\pi^2-1}{2\pi}\right)=\pi\ln(\pi).$

However, the actual answer is $\boxed{2\pi\ln(\pi)}$ and I can't see what I did wrong or what went missing.

Is there something I did that was invalid or is there something I accidentally left?

Comment: I'm guessing you forgot the +C when you integrate back to the original function

Comment: How can you derivate a function respect to a constant like $1+\pi^2$?

Comment: You shouldn't specifically choose $n = 1+\pi^2$ because it doesn't make sense to differentiate a function with respect to a constant. You have to let $n$ be in some interval such that $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{n-2\pi\cos x}dx$ always converges. Try to find what that interval could be, then evaluate $\int_{\text{interval you need}}\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2-4\pi^2}}dn$ and $\int_{\text{interval you need}}I'(n)dn$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to fix it. With what you already obtained
$$I(n) = \int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(n-2\pi\cos x)dx,\>\>\>\>\>I’(n)= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2-4\pi^2}}
$$
evaluate the integral as follows
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(1-2\pi\cos x+\pi^2)dx\\
=& \ I(1+\pi^2)= I(2\pi) + \int_{2\pi}^{1+\pi^2}I’(n)dn\\
=& \int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(2\pi-2\pi\cos x)dx
 + \int_{2\pi}^{1+\pi^2} \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2-4\pi^2}} dn\\
 =&\ \pi\ln(\pi)+ \pi\ln(\pi)=2\pi\ln(\pi)
\end{align}

Comment: What's the reason behind splitting it??

Comment: @MetallicSilver - It is based on $I(b)-I(a)=\int_a^b I’(t)dt$